# What kind of eye does Kirara have in Boruto?

Tags: naruto, boruto

The abilities of other Fabrications are familiar to me like, the particle jutsu used by Ku and Kakō which is from Ōnoki, Sekiei which is the same with Deidara while Kokuyō is not a genjutsu user.

For [Kirara](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kirara), I can't remember any character/clan even from Naruto series that have the same ability. Is her eyes is also a dōjutsu kekkei genkai? What is the name of her eye ability?

[image]